# My method does not execute first

Tags: android, methods

My method from another class named Model.

```
public void coba(){
    Log.i("sdsds","sdsds")
}
```

My activity

```
public class ViewInformasiSiswa extends AppCompatActivity {
Model mod;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mod = new Model();
    mod.coba();
    String a = "5";
    Log.i("coba",a);
}
```

My question is why does `Log.i("coba",a);` this run before my `mod.coba();`
Messages I get:

```
coba 5
sdsds sdsds
```

Comment: what are you trying to say? the method you are calling also post the log. so obvious it will post the log before your main activity log

Comment: no,my logcat that name "coba" show first than my log in my method at another class

Comment: my program should show log cat in my method and afterthat show the log "coba" in main activity,but the fact is,log at my main activity is show up first than my method,although i put my method upside log at main activity

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and this work perfect.  method execute first and then the log appear.

public class Model {

```
public void coba()
{
    Log.i("coba","sdsds");
}
```

}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Model mod;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mod = new Model();
    mod.coba();
    String a = "5";
    Log.i("coba",a);
}
```

}

I think you give the wrong name when you are setting Logcat .Let me know it is helpful for you.